# find usage - command line vs script

Tags: shell, find, quoting

I am seeing different results from the find command between being run manually on the command line vs run in a script.

If I run the following on the command line:

```
find . -name '*.txt' ! -name '*20120427.txt'
```

I get all the .txt files in a directory except for the ones with the date that I want to avoid.

But when I have this same line in a script with a variable to identify the date:

```
FDATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
find . -name '*.txt' ! -name '*${FDATE}.txt'
```

The script finds all the .txt files including the ones with the date I want to avoid.

The only difference between the 2 is that I am passing the FDATE variable in the script. Is there something obvious I am missing? I do not understand why the results are coming out different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the single-quotes in `'*${FDATE}.txt'` to double quotes: `"*${FDATE}.txt"`

Unix shells don't do variable substitution inside single-quoted string literals, but they will do it inside double-quoted string literals.

Comment: @JeffM: Note, that it has nothing at all to do with `find`. It's a shell thing.

Comment: tip: when troubleshooting, run the exact same commands in a shell, in this case set the the FDATE variable and run the command exactly as it is written in the script.